# Microstack -> 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: software-center, nginx

I have a 413 error when I want to create an image on microstack.
Thanks by advance

Bonjour,

J'ai une erreur 413 quand je souhaite créer une image sur microstack fraichement installé.

Merci d'avance pour votre aide

Frédéric

---

```html
<html> <head><title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1></center> <hr><center>nginx/1.13.0</center> </body> </html>
```

[image: Click here to see the error]

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) you will find that nginx limits the upload of file size of server blocks.

```
Syntax: client_max_body_size size;
Default:    
client_max_body_size 1m;
Context:    http, server, location
Sets the maximum allowed size of the client request body, specified in the “Content-Length” request header field. If the size in a request exceeds the configured value, the 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error is returned to the client. Please be aware that browsers cannot correctly display this error. Setting size to 0 disables checking of client request body size.
```

Edit the file `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or
`sudo vim /var/snap/microstack/common/etc/nginx/snap/nginx.conf`:

Set the http client_max_body_size to a size bigger than the iso you want.

```
http {
    ...
    client_max_body_size 2000M;
}
```

now restart it by
`sudo systemctl reload nginx` or `sudo snap restart microstack`